# Is it possible to use Qute templates in a custom extension?

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-qute

I want to develop a Quarkus application that made of multiple independent components (custom extensions). Now, I need to each extension has own qute template; How can I do that?!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

Put `resources/templates/hello.html` and this class in the `deployment` part of your custom extension.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import io.quarkus.qute.Engine;
import io.quarkus.qute.Template;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

@Path("hi")
public class TestQuteTemplateInDeployment {

    public Template getTemplateFromFile(String path2template) {
        Engine engine = Engine.builder().addDefaults().build();
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        String content = "<!doctype html><html></html>";
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(path2template);
            content = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ;
        }
        Template helloTemplate = engine.parse(content);
        return helloTemplate;
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public CompletionStage<String> get() {
        return getTemplateFromFile("templates/hello.html").data("msg", "Hi! I'm Here.").renderAsync();
    }

}
```

Comment: https://quarkus.io/guides/qute-reference#hello_world_example